# Colspan attribute not setting from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with cells that have identical values. I am trying to merge them together using colspan, but setting the attribute for colspan is having no effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/afn4f1q9/4/

```
$(function() {

  $('table.merge tr').each(function() {
    var tr = this;
    var counter = 1;
    var prevValue = false;
    var colspanTD = false;

    $('td', tr).each(function(index, value) {
      var td = $(this);

      if (counter == 1) {
        colspanTD = $(this);
        }

      if (prevValue !== false) {
        if (td.text() == prevValue) {

          if (td.text() != '' && td.text() != 'X' && td.text() != '*') {
            counter++;
            td.remove();

          }
        } else {
          $(colspanTD).attr('colspan', counter );
          counter = 1;
        }

      }
      prevValue = td.text();
    });

  });



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to merge them together using colspan, but setting the attribute for colspan is having no effect.

Your issue is related to some issues with your code. I fixed the problems. Here is my proposal (see the comments in the code).

```js
$('table.merge tr').each(function () {
    var tr = this;
    var counter = -1;
    var prevValue = false;
    var colspanTD = false;
    //
    // save current selection
    //
    var tableCells = $('td', tr)

    tableCells.each(function (index, value) {
        var td = $(this);

        if (prevValue !== false) {
            if (td.text() == prevValue) {
                //
                // get text, trim it and transform in uppercase
                //
                var txt = td.text().trim().toUpperCase();
                if (txt != '' && txt != 'X' && txt != '*') {
                    //
                    // set the starting cell sequence...
                    //
                    if (colspanTD === false) {
                        counter = 1;
                        colspanTD = tableCells.eq(index - 1);
                    }
                    counter++;
                    td.remove();
                }
            } else {
                //
                // if ending cell sequence...
                //
                if (colspanTD !== false) {
                    colspanTD.attr('colspan', counter);
                    colspanTD = false;
                }
            }
        }
        prevValue = td.text();
    });
    //
    // if ending cell sequence in row...
    //
    if (colspanTD !== false) {
        colspanTD.attr('colspan', counter);
        colspanTD = false;
    }

});
```

```css
th,
td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="merge table table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-default">
    <tr>
        <th>Pitch</th>
        <th>Identifier</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-01" data-roomid="22">1</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-02" data-roomid="22">2</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-03" data-roomid="22">3</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-04" data-roomid="22">4</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-05" data-roomid="22">5</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-06" data-roomid="22">6</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-07" data-roomid="22">7</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-08" data-roomid="22">8</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-09" data-roomid="22">9</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-10" data-roomid="22">10</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-11" data-roomid="22">11</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-12" data-roomid="22">12</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-13" data-roomid="22">13</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-14" data-roomid="22">14</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-15" data-roomid="22">15</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-16" data-roomid="22">16</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-17" data-roomid="22">17</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-18" data-roomid="22">18</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-19" data-roomid="22">19</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-20" data-roomid="22">20</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-21" data-roomid="22">21</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-22" data-roomid="22">22</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-23" data-roomid="22">23</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-24" data-roomid="22">24</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-25" data-roomid="22">25</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-26" data-roomid="22">26</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-27" data-roomid="22">27</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-28" data-roomid="22">28</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-29" data-roomid="22">29</th>
        <th class="availability-box-header" data-date="2017-08-30" data-roomid="22">30</th>
        <th class="availability-box-header" data-date="2017-08-31" data-roomid="22">31</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Glade - Electric</td>
        <td>G1</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">771</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">771</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">771</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">771</a>
        </td>
        <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70"
            data-date="2017-08-05" data-block="false">X
        </td>
        <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70"
            data-date="2017-08-06" data-block="false">X
        </td>
        <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70"
            data-date="2017-08-07" data-block="false">X
        </td>
        <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70"
            data-date="2017-08-08" data-block="false">X
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">747</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">747</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">747</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">747</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">747</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">802</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">802</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">802</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">802</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">802</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">802</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1276</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1276</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1276</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1276</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1276</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1276</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1286</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1286</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-28"
            data-block="true"></td>
        <td class="text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-29"
            data-block="true"></td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1194</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1194</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
<br/><br/>

<table class="table table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-default">
    <tr>
        <th>Pitch</th>
        <th>Identifier</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-01" data-roomid="22">1</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-02" data-roomid="22">2</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-03" data-roomid="22">3</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-04" data-roomid="22">4</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-05" data-roomid="22">5</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-06" data-roomid="22">6</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-07" data-roomid="22">7</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-08" data-roomid="22">8</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-09" data-roomid="22">9</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-10" data-roomid="22">10</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-11" data-roomid="22">11</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-12" data-roomid="22">12</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-13" data-roomid="22">13</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-14" data-roomid="22">14</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-15" data-roomid="22">15</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-16" data-roomid="22">16</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-17" data-roomid="22">17</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-18" data-roomid="22">18</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-19" data-roomid="22">19</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-20" data-roomid="22">20</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-21" data-roomid="22">21</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-22" data-roomid="22">22</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-23" data-roomid="22">23</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-24" data-roomid="22">24</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-25" data-roomid="22">25</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-26" data-roomid="22">26</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-27" data-roomid="22">27</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-28" data-roomid="22">28</th>
        <th data-date="2017-08-29" data-roomid="22">29</th>
        <th class="availability-box-header" data-date="2017-08-30" data-roomid="22">30</th>
        <th class="availability-box-header" data-date="2017-08-31" data-roomid="22">31</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Glade - Electric</td>
        <td>G1</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">771</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">771</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">771</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">771</a>
        </td>
        <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70"
            data-date="2017-08-05" data-block="false">X
        </td>
        <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70"
            data-date="2017-08-06" data-block="false">X
        </td>
        <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70"
            data-date="2017-08-07" data-block="false">X
        </td>
        <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70"
            data-date="2017-08-08" data-block="false">X
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">747</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">747</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">747</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">747</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">747</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">802</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">802</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">802</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">802</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">802</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">802</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1276</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1276</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1276</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1276</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1276</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1276</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1286</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1286</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-28"
            data-block="true"></td>
        <td class="text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-29"
            data-block="true"></td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1194</a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="#">1194</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
else {
  this.colSpan = counter
  counter = 1;
}

/**
 *  And Not,
 *  
 *  else {
 *     $(colspanTD).attr('colspan', counter );
 *     counter = 1;
 *  }
 */
```

By the way, your code is a little repetitive. You could do something like :

```js
$(function() {

  $('table.merge tr').each(function() {

    var counter = 1;
    var $prevTD = null;

    $('td', this).each(function(index, value) {

      // We only need the text once.
      var $this = $(this);
      var text = $this.text();

      // We skip if :
      // 1. It's the first td.
      // 2. If the string is empty.
      // 3. The string is a "*" or "X".
      // 4. The current text matches the last text.
      if ($prevTD && text && !/^[*X]$/.test(text) && text == $prevTD.text()) {
        $prevTD.remove();
        this.colSpan = ++counter;
      } 

      // We reset our counter
      else counter = 1;
      
      // We save the current <td>.
      $prevTD = $this;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="merge table table-sm">
  <thead class="thead-default">
    <tr>
      <th>Pitch</th>
      <th>Identifier</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-01" data-roomid="22">1</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-02" data-roomid="22">2</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-03" data-roomid="22">3</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-04" data-roomid="22">4</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-05" data-roomid="22">5</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-06" data-roomid="22">6</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-07" data-roomid="22">7</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-08" data-roomid="22">8</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-09" data-roomid="22">9</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-10" data-roomid="22">10</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-11" data-roomid="22">11</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-12" data-roomid="22">12</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-13" data-roomid="22">13</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-14" data-roomid="22">14</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-15" data-roomid="22">15</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-16" data-roomid="22">16</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-17" data-roomid="22">17</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-18" data-roomid="22">18</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-19" data-roomid="22">19</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-20" data-roomid="22">20</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-21" data-roomid="22">21</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-22" data-roomid="22">22</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-23" data-roomid="22">23</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-24" data-roomid="22">24</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-25" data-roomid="22">25</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-26" data-roomid="22">26</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-27" data-roomid="22">27</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-28" data-roomid="22">28</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-29" data-roomid="22">29</th>
      <th class="availability-box-header" data-date="2017-08-30" data-roomid="22">30</th>
      <th class="availability-box-header" data-date="2017-08-31" data-roomid="22">31</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Glade - Electric</td>
      <td>G1</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">771</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">771</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">771</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">771</a>
      </td>
      <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-05" data-block="false">X</td>
      <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-06" data-block="false">X</td>
      <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-07" data-block="false">X</td>
      <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-08" data-block="false">X</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">747</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">747</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">747</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">747</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">747</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">802</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">802</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">802</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">802</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">802</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">802</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1276</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1276</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1276</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1276</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1276</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1276</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1286</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1286</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-28" data-block="true"></td>
      <td class="text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-29" data-block="true"></td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1194</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1194</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<br /><br />

<table class="table table-sm">
  <thead class="thead-default">
    <tr>
      <th>Pitch</th>
      <th>Identifier</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-01" data-roomid="22">1</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-02" data-roomid="22">2</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-03" data-roomid="22">3</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-04" data-roomid="22">4</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-05" data-roomid="22">5</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-06" data-roomid="22">6</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-07" data-roomid="22">7</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-08" data-roomid="22">8</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-09" data-roomid="22">9</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-10" data-roomid="22">10</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-11" data-roomid="22">11</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-12" data-roomid="22">12</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-13" data-roomid="22">13</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-14" data-roomid="22">14</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-15" data-roomid="22">15</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-16" data-roomid="22">16</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-17" data-roomid="22">17</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-18" data-roomid="22">18</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-19" data-roomid="22">19</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-20" data-roomid="22">20</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-21" data-roomid="22">21</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-22" data-roomid="22">22</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-23" data-roomid="22">23</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-24" data-roomid="22">24</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-25" data-roomid="22">25</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-26" data-roomid="22">26</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-27" data-roomid="22">27</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-28" data-roomid="22">28</th>
      <th data-date="2017-08-29" data-roomid="22">29</th>
      <th class="availability-box-header" data-date="2017-08-30" data-roomid="22">30</th>
      <th class="availability-box-header" data-date="2017-08-31" data-roomid="22">31</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Glade - Electric</td>
      <td>G1</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">771</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">771</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">771</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">771</a>
      </td>
      <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-05" data-block="false">X</td>
      <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-06" data-block="false">X</td>
      <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-07" data-block="false">X</td>
      <td class="availability-box text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-08" data-block="false">X</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">747</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">747</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">747</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">747</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">747</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">802</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">802</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">802</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">802</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">802</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">802</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1276</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1276</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1276</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1276</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1276</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1276</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1286</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1286</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-28" data-block="true"></td>
      <td class="text-center text-danger" data-roomid="22" data-identifier="70" data-date="2017-08-29" data-block="true"></td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#">1194</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```